# Does running R.exe create temporary files?

Tags: r

I'm wondering

- does launching R.exe on **windows** create temporary files and
- does interpreting something like `x <- 5` write to those temporary files?

If temporary files are created where are they stored and what happens if I launch several instances of R.exe? Will they share and overwrite each others temporary files?

Comment: That will depend on your script. Does it call `tempfile()`? Please provide some details on what your script does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each instance of R gets its own temporary directory. You can see that pretty easily below the default temporary directory on your system (eg `/tmp` for me; on Windows I usually set `TEMPDIR` and `TMPDIR` to `C:\TMP` and find them there; I forget where they go otherwise). But when you invoke `tempfile()` or `tempdir()` you can infer the path:

```
R> tempfile()
[1] "/tmp/RtmpDVDtmj/file6a27612c4c83"
R>
```

So the R session in which I typed this uses `/tmp/RtmpDVDtmj/`.

The directory name is randomized and safe from other R instances running at the same time.

At exit of R, the directory is purged.

And no, the simple assignment `x <- 5` will not involve a temporary file.

Comment: It's actually `[1] "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\generated_folder"`.

Comment: I think that varies by Windows version.  XP will still use the older scheme.